# Modifying nginx config directly in memory?

Tags: nginx

This might be a very silly question but I'll still ask it.
Nginx reads nginx.conf file & keeps information in memory/cache until you do a 'nginx -s reload'. 
Is there a way were I can modify nginx configuration directly in memory as I need to do reload multiple times per minute and config file can be huge.

Basically the problem I'm trying to solve is that I have multiple docker containers coming up & down dynamically on a set of host machines. Every time a container comes up, it'll have a different IP & port open (application design constraint). And I'm thinking of using Nginx as reverse proxy. What should I do to solve this problem considering the fact that final product might have 3000 - 5000 containers running on a cluster of hosts. The rate at which containers are launched/destroyed might be around 100 per second.I need a fast way to make sure routing is happening properly

Comment: This looks like an example of the XY Problem (xyproblem.info).  The real question here is why do you have to  reload several times a minute.

Comment: @Dayo I am trying to do a POC where lot of docker containers are coming up and down dynamically. Need to route requests to the right container

Comment: In which case you should edit the question to ask for help with your actual problem.

Comment: Thanks @Dayo for suggestion. Updated problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm, probably not, nginx loads its config in multiple workers, so this does not look like a good idea to try to change it on the fly.

What it your goal ? You seem to need to do some dynamic routing or other sort of treatment. You should instead look at:

- nginx directives and modules such as eval
- Lua scripting
- nginx module dev (in C/C++)

This would allow you to do more or less whatever you want, you can read some config in a db like redis, and change the behavior of your code according to the value in Redis.

For example, you could do a lot just by reading a value in Redis, and then use if directive in your nginx config file. You can use [How can I get the value from Redis and put it in a variable in NGiNX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560531/how-can-i-get-the-value-from-redis-and-put-it-in-a-variable-in-nginx) to get redis value in nginx with eval module.

**UPDATE :**

For dynamic IP in nginx, you should look at [Dynamic proxy_pass to $var with nginx 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743609/dynamic-proxy-pass-to-var-with-nginx-1-0). 
So I would suggest that you :

- have a process that write in redis the IP address of your dockers
- read it with eval and redis module in nginx
- use the value to proxy

Comment: This can be helpful. I'll look into it and will get back with questions :)