# AWS Redis with Nginx and PHP + To many Connections

Tags: php, nginx, redis

I'm using AWS Elasticache Redis and I've been having issues with Redis and to many connections. Using "Info All" I can see the total used connections can grow to around 50,000 in a day.

Currently I'm using PHP to connect to Redis and I have this put into many different php functions so it can be called many times for a single page request. Also PHP session are on redis.

I wanted to ask:
- Can I create a persistent connection to redis from PHP? One connection for all requests to use.
- Should I use a Global PHP variable as a Redis connection that different functions use rather then creating a new connection to redis for each function?
- I've read about Nginx proxying redis requests "redis_pass" - would this connect just once and proxy requests through? would this be a better solution?

Any other solutions?
Just looking for a wise way to reduce the number of redis connections from PHP. (Note: using php 7.0.6).

thanks :)
Adam

Edit:
I noticed you can also get your PHP Session data on Redis via Nginx - would this also reduce connections - I assume yes:
[How can I get the value from Redis and put it in a variable in NGiNX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560531/how-can-i-get-the-value-from-redis-and-put-it-in-a-variable-in-nginx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not helpful, but do you have the redis server secured from the internet? They are often a target for attackers trying to exploit vulnerabilities.